# in android make string layout as table

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

How can I string characters same width
and divide string to columns 
without using tablelayout on xml

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append("aaa    xxx    yy").append("\n");
result.append("b      xxx    yy").append("\n");
result.append("cc     xxx    yy").append("\n");
```

but the result is 
[image: when run app]

Comment: use `\t` instead of `spaces`

Comment: You probably need to use a monospace font so every character has the same width.

Comment: @RahulGaur , \t not working , same problem

Comment: or use an existing ascii-table generator like [this one](https://github.com/freva/ascii-table)